# Unequal number of arguments in inherited method of two child classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods, attributes

I am reading a .txt file containing information about bids and sells of various items. The file rows look something like this:

```
1 | SELL | 100.0 | 12.53

2 | BID | 90.0

3 | BID | 110.0

2 | BID | 115.0
```

The first value in each row represents the user_id, the second represents whether the user put a bid or a sell, the third represents the value of the bid or the sale, and the fourth (only present in SELL rows) represents the time when the sell was placed.

I'd like to create a parent class called `Auction` that contains a `read` method to parse each row, and then two classes `Bids` and `Sells` that inherit this read method. I'd like for `read()` method of the `Bids` class to require only three arguments, and the `read()` method of the `Sells` class to require all arguments. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Auction:
    def __init__(self, user_id, action, price, close_time):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.action = action
        self.price = price
        self.close_time = close_time

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, line):
        row = line.split('|')

        user_id = row[0]
        action = row[1]
        price = row[2]
        close_time = row[3]
        
        return cls(user_id, action, price, close_time)
        
class Bids(Auction):
    def __init__(self, user_id, action, price):
        super().__init__(user_id, action, price)

class Sells(Auction):
    def __init__(self, user_id, action, price, close_time):
        super().__init__(user_id, action, price, close_time)

bids = []
sells = []

with open('Auction_input.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:

        if 'SELL' in line:
            sells.append(Sells.from_string(line))
        elif 'BID' in line:
            bids.append(Bids.from_string(line))
        line = f.readline()
```

Obviously I receive the following error
`TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given` since close_time is not an attribute in the Bids class.

Any thoughts on how to make this work? I don't want to create two read methods for Bids and Sells if the attributes are almost the same.

Comment: Take the `close_time` argument in `Bids` but ignore it by passing `close_time=None` to `super().__init__()`. You should probably also debug your code and step through it as it runs to see what it actually does and if that is what you intended.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and now works!